# How to disable backlight buttons in MTK 6577 phone?

Tags: backlight

I want to get in control of the backlight for my phone buttons (It is a Runbo X5, MTK6577 based).

According to some tutorials I found, I should edit the content of this file:

> /sys/class/leds/button-backlight

that is actually a link to this one:

> /sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/button-backlight/brightness

I "cat"ted the content of the file when the backlight was off and on, and I read values of 0 and 255 respectively.
So far, so good: that file *must* be involved somehow then.

Now, all the documentation I found (for instance [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=40951738)) states that I should manually change that file content according to my will (for instance, 0 if you I the lights to be off), then making the file non-writeable; so that the system can't override the settings.

I did, and it did not worked. Now the file content is *not* overridden; it stays fixed to 0. However, the button keep getting lit as if nothing changed!

I have the feeling that "/sys/devices/platform/leds-mt65xx/leds/button-backlight/brightness" is just where the information about the backlight status is written but not where it is *set*, at least here on my unit (that is, a Runbo X5 phone).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I really want to turn those darn lights off at night.

Thank you!

Comment: Update: I logcat-ted the phone while turning the LEDS on.
Here's what I read:

oldButtonBright=false newButtonBright=true when the leds turned ON, 

and

oldButtonBright=true newButtonBright=false

after some while BUT the light stayed ON for some more time!